# Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: android

Getting the following  error most of the time when I change my device :

> D:\xyz\xyz\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-      mdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha.png (The requested operation cannot be     performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

Comment: Rebuild of project helps but after some time error comes again

Comment: clean the project and rebuild it

Comment: Try putting it in mdpi only

Comment: it helps me for a while ,but when i change my device it again gives error and i have to clean and rebuild it again

Answer (score 0):

If that is a 9 patch image, try putting `abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha.png` inside `drawable` folder itself.

Comment: i am not using that image any where

Comment: if you are using any anti-virus disable it first and rebuild your project.